# Laravel Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. with css animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, laravel

I am pretty new to using jQuery with Laravel and I have a problem with getting it to work. 
(There will be a link to a JSFiddle down below so you can see my code.)

I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.`

I tried multiple ways to use jQuery but neither of these did work

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I also downloaded it locally and saved it in my `public/js` folder, and tried to link it like this:

```
<script src="{{asset('js/jquery-3.3.1.js')}}"></script>
```

But nothing works...

This is the piece of code with the error:

```
$("#a").click(function() {
    $('.transform').toggleClass('transform-active');  });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwnvd/yr9jaw1s/18/)

As you can see it works in the JSFiddle but I can't get it to work in my project.

Comment: this is not a piece of error, the thing is you are calling your script without script src, do ctrl+u on your page and see where is your code and where is jquery.js file is linked

Comment: @SanjitBhardwaj Maybe this is a dumb question but, what do you  meen with there is no src? in the examples above there are. And if I do crl+u they link to the jquery file.

Comment: Are you running any build application like webpack or gulp?

Comment: @SolomonOmokehinde No. Do you need to do that? I thaught that was an option and you don't need to do that.

Comment: If you are not using the in-built front end scaffolding, you would have to manually build your javascript assets package. Laravel >=5.3 uses npm to build assets. If your jQuery is not included as a package, I doubt it would work

Comment: It would work. It depends on the blade however. I'm curious how your blade looks like

Comment: @Indra You can see it in the JSFiddle I included

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Mix ships with jQuery autoloading out of the box. You can find this reference in 
resources/js/bootstrap.js

```
try{
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
}catch(e) {}
```

If it still does not work, all what you need is call mix.autoload before you try to compile other JavaScript files in the webpack.mix.js file.

```
mix.autoload({ 'jquery': ['window.$', 'window.jQuery'] }); 
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js') 
.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Comment: Nice. I understand what you say but, the command for compiling is `npm run dev` isn't it? when I run that command I get some errors like: `npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.` , `npm ERR! Exit status 1` and `npm ERR! errno 1`

Comment: Are you using Laravel without the front-end assets option?